# Can't run command exec(xelatex file.tex)

Tags: php, windows-10, exec, xelatex

I'm trying to generate a pdf from a latex file with the command exec but it doesn't seem to recognize "xelatex".

When I echo any other command like "ls" with exec it works.
Also, the file is generated when I run the command from cmd.

Any idea what the problem might be ?

I'm working on windows10.

Thanks,

Comment: exec's first parameter has to be a string; are you passing the argument in quotes?

Comment: Yes, I am running the command :
`exec("xelatex invoice.tex", $output);`

Comment: Second parameter has to be a reference to an array. If you declared $output = Array(), you need to pass it to exec as "&$output" to pass by reference

Comment: Path... `exec("c:/path/to/xelatex invoice.tex", $output);`